# NSPopOver on mouse hover

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableviewcell, nspopover

I need to display a popover when i place the cursor on a cell of the table view. On OS X app, what is the technique to show a NSPopover when the mouse is over a NSTableViewCell? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [mouseover detection in NSTableView's NSCell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786751/mouseover-detection-in-nstableviews-nscell)

Comment: @trojanfoe you have specified once you did this in your app. Can you pls guide me?

Answer (score 3):

Implement the `mouseMoved:` message for your table view and call `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` from there. Cancel previous requests with `NSObject:cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object` before doing this (and in dealloc). This will constantly restart a timer when the mouse moves. The given selector will be executed after the delay is over and mouse has not been moved since then. In the selector you can then get the current mouse position and show the popover.

Don't forget to remove the popover when the mouse starts moving again.