# How to create table with highlighted-on-mouseover cells on macOS cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa, mouseover, nstablecellview

I'm trying to create a tray popover app with table very similar to the one Dropbox has in it's popover view.
There is a table of files and when you hover mouse over a table cell, cell will highlight and show additional controls.
I'm not sure if NSTableView is suitable for this at all?
Does anyone have any advice?

[image: Dropbox Popover Table WIth Highlighted Cell]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would be an ideal use of `NSTableView`. Using a view-based NSTableView, you'll be easily able to create the look of those cells (views). The highlight on mouse-over should be accomplishable if you add an `NSTrackingArea` to the table view (scroll view might be better) with `-[NSView addTrackingArea:]`, which gives you callbacks for `-mouseMoved:` events. From that method you can use the `locationInWindow` property on the NSEvent, and then use NSTableView's `-rowAtPoint:` call to query which row you should change to display the hover event.

Comment: Are you suggesting putting a single tracking area on the table view, or separate tracking areas on each cell view?

Comment: @sam Single tracking area on the entire table view. You want to avoid adding multiple tracking areas if possible. It's probably much easier to maintain with 1 tracking area anyway.

Comment: @sam Might want to actually do the scroll view instead of the entire table view. Not sure if it really matters much, but it's a smaller area to track.

Answer (score 0):

As a possible amendment here, I had to do the following to make this work:

```
highlightedRow: MyCustomRow?

func viewWillAppear(){
    configureTableHighlight()
}

func configureTableHighlight() {
    let trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(rect: scrollView.frame, options: [.mouseMoved, .activeInKeyWindow, .inVisibleRect], owner: self, userInfo: nil)
    scrollView.addTrackingArea(trackingArea)
}

override func mouseMoved(with event: NSEvent) {
    let pointInTableView = tableView.convert(event.locationInWindow, to: nil)
    let row = tableView.row(at: pointInTableView)
    
    if row == -1 {
        highlightedRow?.highlight = false
        highlightedRow = nil
        return
    }
    
    guard let view = tableView.view(atColumn: 0, row: row, makeIfNecessary: false) as? MyCustomRow else {
        return
    }
    
    if(highlightedRow == view){
        return
    }
    
    view.highlight = true;
    highlightedRow?.highlight = false
    highlightedRow = view;
}
```

This might depend on where you add the trackingView however.

Additional reference:

[mouseover detection in NSTableView's NSCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786751/mouseover-detection-in-nstableviews-nscell)